# Align text to image in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I am copying a website and I cant seem to do this properly like this

```
______________________
|                    |
|OOOO Hello there    |
|OOOO I just want    |
|OOOO to align this  |
|Text in this image. |
|____________________|
```

The OOOO stands for the image.

I do float:left; the image and the text. but the text seems not responding. Any help?

Comment: i'd say `align=left` and then css would find me in my sleep and kill me

Comment: align=left will just make the image left, but the text will not be carry over to the remaining space.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/nakimafoci/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine with float

```css
img{
    float:left;
    margin: 20px
}
```

```html
<article>
    <img src=http://placehold.it/150x150 />
    <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.    
</div>
</article>
```